# How can you set SourceData in a macro to count only rows needed?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel Workbook in which I am building as a Master.  Part of what I have to do is have pie charts on my master sheet.  So I have created a sheet that has formulas pulling over selected information to use for the pie charts (SortedPie).  Then I have another sheet that will be populated by macro creating the pivot tables for the pie charts (PieSheet).  My problem is that the information on SortedPie changes in the amount of rows from 1 to 500.  In my macro I have the SourceData set to 500, but then it leaves blanks in the pivot tables to equal all 500 rows.  I have tried using   `lr=SortedPie.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` with `set rng=SortedPie.range("A:X" & lr)` then for `SourceData=:rng.Address(True, True,xlR1C1,True).Refresh`  and when run gives me compile error on the Address.  I should say my code also has `Dim lr As Long` and `Dim rng As Range`.  This is the macro as it is now.

```
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "SortedPie!R1C1:R500C5", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable _
    TableDestination:="PieSheet!R1C1", TableName:="PivotTable2", _
    DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14
Sheets("PieSheet").Select
cells(1, 1).Select
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Credit Score")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable2").PivotFields("CustomerAccountID"), "Count of CustomerAccountID", _
    xlCount
Sheets("SortedPie").Select
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "SortedPie!R1C1:R185C5", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable _
    TableDestination:="PieSheet!R10C1", TableName:="PivotTable3", _
    DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14
Sheets("PieSheet").Select
cells(10, 1).Select
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("PanelType")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable3").PivotFields("CustomerAccountID"), "Count of CustomerAccountID", _
    xlCount
Sheets("SortedPie").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PieSheet").PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotCache. _
    CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="PieSheet!R20C1", TableName:= _
    "PivotTable4", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14
Sheets("PieSheet").Select
cells(20, 1).Select
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("Status")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable4").PivotFields("CustomerAccountID"), "Count of CustomerAccountID", _
    xlCount
Sheets("SortedPie").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PieSheet").PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotCache. _
    CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="PieSheet!R30C1", TableName:= _
    "PivotTable5", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14
Sheets("PieSheet").Select
cells(30, 1).Select
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields("BillingMethod")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable5").PivotFields("CustomerAccountID"), "Count of CustomerAccountID", _
    xlCount
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the activesheet.usedrange.address to get the actual address of the entire worksheet, or assign the range to a variable via:
    Dim rUsedRange as range

```
set rUsedRange = activesheet.usedrange
```

UsedRange always gives the active area of a worksheet and updates anytime additional rows or columns are added. If you use the clearcontents command to clear a worksheet before repopulating, the usedrange will reset to a smaller size if needed.

You can also get the bottom row via:

```
lRow = activesheet.usedrange.rows.count
```

Comment: This is most likely something I am doing wrong, but I used the Dim, set and lRow from above then put `rUsedrange.Address(True, True, x1R1C1, True).Refresh` for the SourceData:= in the macro above and get a compile error invalid qualifier on .Address.  Sorry,  I am still a noob on writing macros, so what have I done wrong?

Comment: rUsedRange is a range that is the size of the used cells of the worksheet. when you run the macro in trace mode, type rUsedRange.address in the immediate window and you will see it return the activesheet's entire range (i.e. all rows, all columns) It is a property not a method, so you can assign a range to it use the name as a reference to the range, but you cannot use it as a method (i.e. .Refresh)

Comment: In your original problem you were looking for a way to count the total rows. lRow = Activesheet.usedrange.rows.count will give the the count of rows of the active sheet, without having to use the End(x1Up).Row property.